# Oracle - where the orderly column ID e.g. ORDER BY 1 is allwed?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

## Question

What are the rules where the orderly column ID 1, 2, ... is allowed? From which part of document can I tell?

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT Months * Salary, COUNT(*)
    FROM Employee
    GROUP BY (Months * Salary) 
    ORDER BY 1 DESC     <---- This is OK
    )
WHERE ROWNUM = 1;

----------
108064 7
```

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT Months * Salary, COUNT(*)
    FROM Employee
    GROUP BY 1        <--- ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
    ORDER BY 1 DESC
    )
WHERE ROWNUM = 1;

----------
SELECT Months * Salary, COUNT(*)
*
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
```

For this case, which document can tell it is not allowed and why?

- [group_by_clause::=](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6)

[image]

- [order_by_clause::=](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6)

[image]

Comment: Can you see `position` in the second of those diagrams - but not the first?

Comment: Oracle has the most precise documentation I've ever seen, so look at the `expression` definition and explanation of `position` meaning. There should be all the details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- In the `GROUP BY` clause the `1` is a number literal value.
- In the `ORDER BY` clause the `1` refers to the the first term of the `SELECT` clause.

If you do:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM Employee
    GROUP BY 1              -- A number literal
    ORDER BY 1 DESC
    )
WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

It is the same as:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM Employee
    GROUP BY NULL           -- A NULL literal
    ORDER BY 1 DESC
    )
WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

or

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM Employee
    GROUP BY 'ABC'          -- A string literal
    ORDER BY 1 DESC
    )
WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

However,

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT Months * Salary, COUNT(*)
    FROM Employee
    GROUP BY 1
    ORDER BY 1 DESC
    )
WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

Is not valid as `1` is a literal number value that you are grouping by whereas `Months` and `Salary` are column names that are in a `GROUP BY` query but are not aggregated.

Answer (score 1):

In the images only in order-by you can find the "position" option.
Also, from "Java DB Technical Documentation":

```
GROUP BY 
{
    column-Name [ , column-Name ]*  
|
    ROLLUP ( column-Name [ , column-Name ]* )
}
column-Name must be a column from the current scope of the query;
there can be no columns from a query block outside the current scope.
For example, if a GROUP BY clause is in a subquery,
it cannot refer to columns in the outer query.

ORDER BY { column-Name | ColumnPosition | Expression }
    [ ASC | DESC ]
    [ NULLS FIRST | NULLS LAST ]
    [ , column-Name | ColumnPosition | Expression 
    [ ASC | DESC ]
    [ NULLS FIRST | NULLS LAST ]
    ] * 

ColumnPosition
An integer that identifies the number of the column in the SelectItems
in the underlying query of the SELECT statement.
ColumnPosition must be greater than 0 and not greater
than the number of columns in the result table. In other words,
if you want to order by a column, that column must be specified
in the SELECT list.
```

Comment: How is Java DB documentation relevant to Oracle DB?

Answer (score 0):

Positional integer column ID is available in ORDER BY but not in GROUP BY.

## Positional ORDER BY notation

> position
>
> Specify position to order rows based on their value for the expression
> in this position of the select list. **The position value must be an
> integer**.
>
> You can specify multiple expressions in the order_by_clause. Oracle
> Database first sorts rows based on their values for the first
> expression. Rows with the same value for the first expression are then
> sorted based on their values for the second expression, and so on. The
> database sorts nulls following all others in ascending order and
> preceding all others in descending order. Refer to "Sorting Query
> Results" for a discussion of ordering query results.

> To select the same information as the previous SELECT and use the
> positional ORDER BY notation, issue the following statement, which
> orders by ascending department_id, then descending salary, and finally
> alphabetically by last_name:

```
SELECT last_name, department_id, salary 
   FROM employees 
   ORDER BY 2 ASC, 3 DESC, 1;
```